# Python string literal throwing errors with place holders

Tags: python, string, python-2.x, string-literals

I have a list as :
`token_found = ["abcdxyz", "1234567"]`

I have a multiline string as below:

```
user_creds_string = """
UserA_A:
    - name: 'Abcd'
      value: '{0}'
UserB_B:
    - name: 'Abcd'
      value: '{1}'
headers:
  - name: 'Abcd'
    value: 'Kota %(xyz)'
    inputs:
      apop: {'type':'hex-64', 'required': True} 
  - name: 'X-Broke'
    value: '%(BId) %(blahId)'
    inputs:
      UkID: {'type':'hex-16', 'required': True} 
      blahId: {'type':'hex-64', 'required': True} 
apis:
    """.format(token_found[0],token_found[1])
```

Now when I run the above code I expect that the place holders `{0}` and `{1}` to be replaced with the values `abcdxyz` and `1234567` respectively, unless I am doing something wrong and which I do not understand.

Contrary to my assumption, I am getting the below error:
`KeyError: "'type'"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

curly brackets `{`, `}` should be doubled to print them literally:

```
token_found = ["abcdxyz", "1234567"]
user_creds_string = """
UserA_A:
    - name: 'Abcd'
      value: '{0}'
UserB_B:
    - name: 'Abcd'
      value: '{1}'
headers:
  - name: 'Abcd'
    value: 'Kota %(xyz)'
    inputs:
      apop: {{'type':'hex-64', 'required': True}}
  - name: 'X-Broke'
    value: '%(BId) %(blahId)'
    inputs:
      UkID: {{'type':'hex-16', 'required': True}}
      blahId: {{'type':'hex-64', 'required': True}}
apis:
    """.format(token_found[0],token_found[1])

print(user_creds_string)
```

The output:

```
UserA_A:
    - name: 'Abcd'
      value: 'abcdxyz'
UserB_B:
    - name: 'Abcd'
      value: '1234567'
headers:
  - name: 'Abcd'
    value: 'Kota %(xyz)'
    inputs:
      apop: {'type':'hex-64', 'required': True}
  - name: 'X-Broke'
    value: '%(BId) %(blahId)'
    inputs:
      UkID: {'type':'hex-16', 'required': True}
      blahId: {'type':'hex-64', 'required': True}
apis:
```

Comment: thanks ! I did not know this. :)

Comment: @qre0ct, you're welcome

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the `{`. `format` sees the pattern `{'type'` and tries to do a lookup of `'type'` in the `kwargs` of `format`.

Escape as I recall is to double the brace, `{{`.

Comment: Yeah, got that from Roman's answer above. Thanks anyway :)